# Swing JList: how to show String from an object?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

this confuses me. 
i add objects in JList , like below:

```
public class RequestListModel extends AbstractListModel<Request> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private List<Request> data = null;

public RequestListModel (List<Request> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public int getSize() {
    return this.data.size();
}

@Override
public Request getElementAt(int index) {
    Request request = data.get(index);
    return request;
}}

private JList<Request> getList() {
    ListModel<Request> model = new RequestListModel(this.requestList);
    if(jlist_from == null) {
        jlist_from = new JList<Request>(model);
    } else {
        jlist_from.setModel(model);
    }
    return jlist_from;
}
```

but when i run the program, it just shows the object's address :
[image]

so how would i show the text from the object ?
thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it just show the object's address

The default renderer for a `JList` simply invokes the `toString()` method of the object, which by default is the objects address.

You should provide a custom renderer for your JList. The render allows you to access the object and display any data from the object in any format that you wish. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using a Custom Renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer).

A simpler solution is to implement a custom `toString()` method in your object. Although this approach is not recommended since the toString() should be used to describe the object when debugging.

Also, there is no reason to create a custom `ListModel`. You can just use the `DefaultListModel` to hold your Request objects.

Comment: much thanks for your kindly help , camickr